# How do I unit test and integration test my SSIS packages?

Tags: sql-server, unit-testing, ssis, integration-testing, etl

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/226605/how-do-i-perform-automated-unit-testing-in-ssis-packages) mentions two libraries, both of which aren't maintained and one has broken links to the source and documentation.

[SSISUnit](http://ssisunit.codeplex.com/) was last updated in 2008 and [SSIStester](https://ssistester.codeplex.com/) has broken links in the documentation and hasn't been updated since 2013.

The answers on *social.msdn.microsoft.com* also generally point to one of those two libraries, or some sort of custom solution.

Are there any other options?

---

## 2018-10-09 Bounty Update

Is there any updates that are related to newer versions of SSIS (2015+)?

I have already checked similar questions:

- [Unit testing of SSIS Package with tSQLt](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17447994/unit-testing-of-ssis-package-with-tsqlt)
- [How to test the SSIS Packages?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2800789/how-to-test-the-ssis-packages)
- [Unit testing data flow in a ssis package](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/481168/unit-testing-data-flow-in-a-ssis-package)

Answer (score 19, accepted):

The most Basic way to perform a SSIS Unit Testing is to create your own testing package. Example below:

- [BUILDING AN SSIS TESTING FRAMEWORK](https://kzhendev.wordpress.com/2014/05/21/building-an-ssis-testing-framework/)

The Most popular Tools to perform SSIS Unit Testing are the ones you listed:

- SSISUnit
- SSISTester

But after making a deep search i found a new way that is [BizUnit](https://github.com/BizUnit/BizUnit).  `BizUnit Framework` which is predominantly used for the Biz Unit testing can be customized to test SSIS Package as well. More info in the link below

- [SSIS:Automated Unit Testing](https://msbistack.blogspot.com/2011/10/automated-unit-testing-for-ssis-using.html)

Also if you mean by testing Package Validation (metadata , connections , ...etc),  you can follow my answer in this SO question

- [How to get all errors of all SSIS packages in a solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42577741/how-to-get-all-errors-of-all-ssis-packages-in-a-solution)