# Validate dtsx packages outside Visual Studio

Tags: sql-server, visual-studio-2012, ssis, sql-server-2012

**Background:** Our application is split into a Database project and a SSIS project. Right now, it can occur that a change is pushed on the DB project (like a column name change) that will go unnoticed until runtime when a package is failing that tries to use that column. As part of our integration build, I want to validate the packages in the SSIS project against the database, so we can detect these kind of errors earlier.

**Question:** How can I validate our dtsx packages so that I can detect errors in the design during an integration build?

Preferred solution: I want to have a list of errors for all packages that are mismatching to database objects like I see when I open the package in design view:

```
Error   4   Validation error. 
My_Package_Name [40]: SSIS Error Code DTS_E_OLEDBERROR.  
An OLE DB error has occurred. Error code: 0x80040E14.  
An OLE DB record is available.  
Source: "Microsoft SQL Server Native Client 11.0"  Hresult: 0x80040E14  
Description: "Statement(s) could not be prepared.".  An OLE DB record is available.  
Source: "Microsoft SQL Server Native Client 11.0"  Hresult: 0x80040E14  
Description: "Invalid column name 'MyRenamedColumn'.".      
My_Package_Name.dtsx    0   0
```

Ideally: running the "Design Warnings Scanner" from the command line and capturing the errors and warnings.

Already tried:

1. Running DTEXEC.exe from commandline. But because we are using Connection Managers instead of in-package variables for the database connections, DTEXEC does not run without errors.
2. Validating packages programmatically with the `Validate()` method on the package as `Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Runtime.Package` object. This will always succeed (even on packages that use faulty columns). Adding the sqlserver connection manually through the `Connections` collection does not help.

Comment: Have you tried to deploy packages on SSIS Catalog and validate it on the SSIS Server? I use this approach for DB-Package match test; among the advantages - you can use environments to specify Connection Managers.

Comment: Look at my answer here. maybe it is different to what you have tried http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42577741/how-to-get-all-errors-of-all-ssis-packages-in-a-solution

Comment: Thank you both for the replies. I am still in the investigation phase and will take these options certainly into account! I'll post my final solution when I've found one.