# How to Review queries written in SSIS Packages within Visual Studio?

Tags: sql-server, visual-studio, ssis, ssms, etl

How do we improve the coding standards of SSIS packages?

Is there any code review tool within Visual Studio that helps to improves the standards of  queries and  tasks used in the SSIS package?

For Example, we have an execute SQL Task(naming convention not followed) and have written SQL complex query with poor coding standards.

In this scenario, is there any tool within Visual Studio that helps to give a review report and help to improve coding standards for SQL queries and naming conventions for Tasks?

We have tools like SQL Enlight, but it's available only within SSMS, We have SSIS code check-in VS, but it won't review codes within the tasks.

please let me know if there is a combined tool within VS to review

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

You can check the Visual Studio for a code check extension such as [SSIS Code Check](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=MAQSoftware.SSISCodeCheck)

Also, it is good to create unit tests for the SSIS packages: [How do I unit test and integration test my SSIS packages?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38461772/how-do-i-unit-test-and-integration-test-my-ssis-packages/43590097#43590097)